# How to set default code pages in visual studio while automating a data load process

Tags: .net, ssis, automation

I have few csv files and I used load them manually into database using SSIS and get the data into application in the format that I wanted.

Now the count of files and the count of records in those files increased.

So I automated the process using .net code and used it in SSIS. Its working fine most of the time but in few cases the process is failing to load the data from specific files. When I tried to manually load the same file into same table manually, I found that all those files had code page : 65001 and all the other files were 1252.

I changed the code page to 1252 in connection manager and it is loading fine.

Can someone tell me how to set a default code page in the .net code so that I can avoid this manual load

Comment: Could you elaborate on .Net part. What you are doing with it - exporting CSV for SSIS or parsing data inside SSIS?

Comment: @Ferdipux I have a column list for each table along with the table name in a separate table. When I receive a file I'm comparing the file name with the table name I have and the file header with the column list I have. Now if they match I'm separating the rows and columns in the file using the delimiters and loading the data into SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `code page 1252` as below in snapshot mentioned below.

[image]

Comment: I'm already using this but still its not working for such files. see that part of the code :                                                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(row(i))